# TeX instead of Preview, LaTeX and Command menus after upgrade of AucTeX

Tags: auctex

I upgraded AucTeX to 12.1.2, hoping that it would fix a problem with the displaying of verbatim environments.

This caused a range of problems which I am trying to track down step by step.

One is that the Preview, LaTeX and Command menus disappeared. Instead, I now have a "TeX" menu right of "Tools". The mode displayed in the status bar is "LaTeX", though.

This seems wrong to me. There are more things that are broken, but I'd like to start with that.

Comment: It seems you are using Emacs' default LaTeX mode, not AUCTeX. In order to load AUCTeX, you normally need to do `(require 'tex-site)` as part of your Emacs initialization. I guess you don't have `:override advice: ‘TeX-latex-mode’` in the buffer obtained when typing `C-h m` in a buffer visiting a LaTeX file. With Emacs' default LaTeX mode, you should see `LaTeX mode defined in ‘tex-mode.el’:` followed by `Major mode for editing files of input for LaTeX.`, whereas with AUCTeX, one gets pointed to an override that leads to an ELisp file which is part of AUCTeX.

Comment: Indeed, I see `LaTeX mode defined in ‘tex-mode.el`. However, adding `(require 'tex-site)` I get `File local-variables error: (void-function TeX-latex-mode)`.

Comment: I also have `tex-mode.el` mentioned first with AUCTeX in the `*Help*` buffer, but *then* comes the override I mentioned. Where did you put this `(require 'tex-site)`? How did you install AUCTeX? It should always provide `'tex-site`, AFAIK.

Comment: Originally, my installation worked. Then, I upgraded to AucTeX 12.1.2 from elpa with M-x package-list-packages, followed by "U". This is the setup I cannot get to work. I now deleted 12.1.2, emacs uses 12.1.1 again, and everything works. The :override advice: also shows up. Really strange. The `(require 'text-site)` was in `.emacs`, but I think with the elpa installation it should not be there.

Comment: It's `'tex-site`, not `'text-site`, but you probably knew that. My diagnostic is that your AUCTeX 12.1.2 wasn't completely installed, since you reported `(void-function TeX-latex-mode)`, and this function is shipped with AUCTeX (and not with standard Emacs). I can't really help more, as I never use the `package.el` stuff. I install AUCTeX from the Git repo, just tested the [current latest commit](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/auctex.git/commit/?id=cd3996645123ff65659f06acb2851b26720309af), no problem. I wrote a short installation script to ease upgrades, can share if you are on Linux.

Comment: `text-site` was just a typo in my answer, it was correct in `.emacs`. You were right about the incomplete installation, I think. I just re-installed 12.1.2 and now it works as expected. Thanks for the hint.